# Specify the order of execution for a Blender plugin and an external script?

Tags: scripting, command-line

I'm trying to use an external script at the same time with a Blender plugin but I am having a few issues because I believe the script is being computed/processed before the plugin and for this situation I would need it to go after the plugin.

Is there a way to check and/or change the order in which scripts / plugins are computed?